# How do I get mediafilesegmenter to generate encrypt keys so that I can serve them locally?

Tags: ios, encryption, command-line, http-live-streaming

I think I'm missing something about mediafilesegmenter.

The docs say this about encrypting content:

> The media stream segmenter available from Apple provides encryption
>   and supports three modes for configuring encryption. The first mode
>   allows you to specify a path to an existing key file on disk. In this
>   mode the segmenter inserts the URL of the existing key file in the
>   index file. It encrypts all media files using this key. The second
>   mode instructs the segmenter to generate a random key file, save it in
>   a specified location, and reference it in the index file. All media
>   files are encrypted using this randomly generated key. The third mode
>   instructs the segmenter to generate a new random key file every n
>   media segments, save it in a specified location, and reference it in
>   the index file. This mode is referred to as key rotation. Each group
>   of n files is encrypted using a different key.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW3

The docs say this about mediafilesegmenter:
The file segmenter performs the same tasks as the stream segmenter, but it takes files as input instead of streams.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-DontLinkElementID_7

So, I'm guessing mediafilesegmenter has those three modes, just like mediastreamsegmenter does. I'm trying to use the second mode. Here's my command:

> mediafilesegmenter -f encryptedSegmentsDirectory -encrypt-iv=sequence
>   -encrypt-key encryptedSegmentsDirectory/key.txt media.m4v

The result is .ts files and two m3u8 files, neither of which seem to reference key files. I get this response:
mediafilesegmenter: option `-encrypt-key' is ambiguous
Is there an example that shows how to do this successfully?

Also, HTTP Live Streaming seems to insist on serving key files over http:

> You can serve key files using either HTTP or HTTPS. You may also
>   choose to protect the delivery of the key files using your own
>   session-based authentication scheme. For details, see “Serving Key
>   Files Securely Over HTTPS.”

I'd like to serve it on a local file on the iOS file system instead from a server. Is this possible? If not, would there any problem with serving it from a local web server?

Sorry if I missed something obvious - please feel free to just point me to the relevant documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Doh - I got the switch wrong. It's -encrypt-key-file, not -encrypt-key. Sorry, everyone! I just needed to step away for a while.